# Image Upload at Google Appengine using AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-app-engine

I'm trying to upload an image on Google appengine hosting using ajax and php and I always get server error 500

My approach is create upload url which will be later used to submit the form to:

```
<?php
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload_script', $options);
```

The form which will be submitted as soon as any change is made to the input type file:

```
<form <?php echo 'action="$upload_url"'; ?> enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Files to upload: <br>
   <input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Since I'm doing it using AJAX here is the ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form').on('submit',(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data:formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(){
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    }));

    $("#browse").on("change", function() {
        $("#form").submit();
    });
});
```

This produces server error 500 when looking on it in console does anyone know where might be the problem?

Comment: contentType should be something like "image/jpeg", not false.